# How do I create a list of URLs in Google Data Studio so that I can compare how they change over time?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-data-studio

I want to have a report (in Google Data Studio) showing a list of URLs to see how they improved over time.

I thought I could escape my URLs and then use a list like:

`\/blog|\/other-page|\/yet-another-page`

Those are just examples, pages could contain a variety of characters which would possibly need to be escaped.

Is there a way to escape all characters for Google Analytics?  Or do you have to do each one individually?  I have a lot of URLs in this particular case as I am updating a lot of meta titles and descriptions.  So I want to see how they compare to previous periods after the change.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the "/" cause it's not a special character. So, your code would be:

```
/blog|/other-page|/yet-another-page
```

You can also use a short method like

```
^/(blog|other-page|yet-another-page)
```

Comment: I thought anything non-alphanumeric would need to be escaped.

Comment: Even so, same question, as some of the items defo have things in there that would need to be escaped.  Is there a shorter way to do the escaping?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the best way, if you already know the URLs, which I get from Excel on this occasion is to put them all into one place and then use a tool like this

https://www.regex-escape.com/regex-escaping-online.php

Which says:

> Which regex-characters must be escaped? Special characters in regular
>   expressions which have to be escaped are:. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = !
>   < > | : -

Using the below sentance which incorporates all of the items I can test it

`eoin-oliver\is+a*wonderful?person[I^think]we$can(all)agree{somewhat}=to!a<god>or|oxymoron:nice`